# File Privacy on Records field is not visible in Edit File details opened from row actions in Related Files

Tags: files, contentversion, fileupload

I've included File Privacy on Records field to ContentVersion object layout and it is shown everywhere except when I click "*View All*" on Files related list on record page and then "*Edit File Details*" in row actions on one of the files.

For example here is a comparison between edit window when I open it from file preview (picture 1) and from row actions (picture 2)

Is it possible to add this field to the edit window from picture 2, or it is a limitation of Salesforce?

[image]

[image]